# Canvas not binding to mouse button within a class, tkinter-Python3

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have been trying to bind a canvas to mouse click as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29211864/5313058) but within a class. The `callback` function is not getting invoked though. All [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44876264/binding-not-working-tkinter-python3) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38619393/attaching-event-to-self-canvas-tkinter) here seem to be calling the `callback()` function while trying to bind, rather than referencing it. I am referencing it, but it still doesn't work.

```
from tkinter import *

class BindingTrial():
    def __init__(self,root,canvas):
        self.root = root
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.canvas.bind("Button-1",self.callback)

    def callback(self,event):
        print ("clicked at", event.x, event.y)

root = Tk()
canvas= Canvas(root, width=100, height=100)
bt = BindingTrial(root,canvas)
canvas.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the button bind with `"<Button-1>"`, and the callback should accept self as the first parameter.

```
class BindingTrial():
    def __init__(self,root,canvas):
        self.root = root
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.canvas.bind('<Button-1>',self.callback)

    def callback(self, event):
        print ("clicked at", event.x, event.y)
```